# how to append a column to a model from a relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a model and a relationship which i want to append a column from a relationship to the model so every time every where that the model is called that column from the relationship should be shown in model column .
i want to sort the model by that column and the second problem is that the column is `updated_at` so if i can rename that to any other column name that would be very fine . so here is my relationship and model code :
my model :

```
  public function statusHistory(){
        return $this->hasMany(WishStatusHistory::class);
    }
  public function setUpdatedAtAttribute(){
        $this->statusHistory->updated_at;
    }
```

Comment: updated sorry it was not pasted

Comment: did you mean adding a custom attribute to a model at runtime?

Comment: yes i want to add the updated_at column from a relationship to my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an accessor as below.

```
public function getNewUpdatedAtAttribute()
{
    return $this->statusHistory->updated_at;
}
```

Then add the attribute name to the appends property on the model

```
protected $appends = ['new_updated_at']; // Modified column name. You can use any. make sure you update the same in method as well
```

To sort the results using appended column use `sortBy` method. (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby)

```
$model = Model::all();
$model = $model->sortBy(function($m){
    return $m->new_updated_at;
});
```

Comment: i did like u said but when i called :         dd($data->new_updated_at); it returns null

Comment: For the status history, you have set `hasMany` relationship. You need to return `updated_at` value of the last status row(single row).

Comment: i changed that return on accessor to a test value like this :        return 'asd';

Comment: but yet again nothing shows up in model thats so wierd

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo error. I have corrected the answer. We need to use `getNewUpdatedAtAttribute`.

Comment: yes thats right . thanks for the answer but now when i dd that i can see that but when i sort that after paginate or before it says that this property does not exists on collection

Comment: ay way i accepted your answer because it helped me get that .

Comment: Use `sortBy` to sort the results using the new column. I have updated the answer to include sorting code. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could try this in your model:

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute()
{
   return $this->statusHistory->updated_at;
}

// then;
$model->updated_at;
```